# Play mp4 Video using <Embed> tag on Android Webview

Tags: android

I want to play mp4 video using  tag on Webview. I have few constraints for not to use HTML5  tag. I have looked code to play YouTube video on webview. But YouTube uses .flv format. I have .mp4 video to play.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell me if it is possible or not ??

Answer (score 1):

You could play the video directly, without a `WebView`:

```
VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);
setContentView(videoView);

Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
if (null != extra && extra.containsKey("url")) {
    String url = extra.getString("url");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);

    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.start();
}
```

Comment: I want to play using webview only. Do you have any way to play using WebView. Because I am playing this from local html file.